# Impact field in OTRS 5.0.13

Tags: otrs

I am new to linux. I am looking into OTRS.

I installed OTRS 4 and have upgraded to 5.0.13 and the upgrade was seamless.
I have not managed to find the solution for this problem I have.

I see 2 Dynamic fields already created by system by the name ITSMImpact and ITSMCriticality.(These got installed after I installed packages) Here is my problem.

When I am trying to create a ticket on behalf of the user

1. I am seeing that the impact field is present but has no dropdowns
2. I am seeing that the criticality field is not present.

I am so confused due to the numerous fields in sysconfig. Not even sure how to search. Can someone be kind enough to tell me which module should I go to so I can find the fields listed during

- Creating a new Phone ticket
- Creating a new Email ticket

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your upgrade went wrong. This hasn't got so much to do with programming - you might best ask on the OTRS forums or mailing lists: http://forums.otterhub.org/

Comment: I am not getting any reply from there!!

I am seeing the impact dynamic field greyed out when I am trying to raise a ticket. Otherwise I can add additional states to it & configure it.